# Serializing GameObject references

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture

Project I'm working on has some peculiar design requirements and I'm trying to find a solution that satisfies them (and realizing that "this is not possible" is likely).

1. 3D models will be stored in one or more asset bundles that will be referenced, so that future updates can be pushed to multiple applications with minimal effort (40 programs do not need to be recompiled).
2. Asset bundles are considered volatile to a degree (they can change externally in order to allow 3D and texture assets to be updated, updates should **never** require a recompile of the Unity exe).
3. No code can be included in asset bundles (multiple reasons; primarily that Unity can't run code not present in its dll, so script assets have to be present in the base application; there's also an issue of overhead: these models are very finely detailed, hundreds of parts (literally down to individual screws), each of which could be individually intractable).

I need to find a way, both editor and runtime, to be able to uniquely reference the individual parts of the 3D assets so that application developers can specify which bits are to have functionality and of what kind, while runtime the application needs to be able to find this bits in order to apply the functionality.

Options considered and their drawbacks:

- Transform hierarchy object names. Will break if an object gets renamed, moved (reparented), or deleted (possible, if unlikely, creates invisible dependencies). Violates requirement #2.
- Using GUIDs. Requires every object in the hierarchy to have an attached script storing the information. Violates requirement #3.
- Using asset bundles as included (compiled into the project) resources. Violates requirement #1.
- Unity asset bundle addressables. Currently not ready for production use, will not be ready in time for this project's delivery deadline.

Comment: I would go with the transform names and consider it a rule for assets. It is the same with e.g. using interfaces or reflection -> the names simply have to match the template and may not be different/misspelled etc.

Comment: @derHugo  That's pretty much the only thing I've decided will work too. I just know that some where down the line someone will screw the pooch  (because assets won't be versioned, well, they'll *have* a version identifier, but older versions won't be stored or distributed).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with transform names, but with a twist: List the transforms in a file (JSON or whatever) and give each a GUID, then include that in the bundle as well. You'd essentially be using the GUID option, but without scripts. If the hierarchy changes, you can simply edit the metadata file, so it'll also satisfy the no recompile requirement.

Comment: How is the metadata file edited? How are guids assigned? Remember I'm working with very large data sets here, upwards of 1000 objects (I haven't yet gotten my hands on the production asset to see how many are actually there, but having seen an older app similar to what we're doing, 800 to 1800 GOs is good estimate). It has to be automated and if an object is reparented, it *must* keep the same guid.

Comment: That's for you to solve based on your project's requirements, but you'd need an editor script to generate the file and *some* way to identify the objects. You could perhaps cache the names (and hope they don't change) in a file in your editor, and use that as reference to find reparented objects. New objects get random IDs.

Comment: If you think you can devise a system to always track all changes from all artists and never break, you're welcome to try, but don't expect to get too far.

Comment: I didn't write the specification. I just have to implement it. And if there isn't a perfect solution, then that's an answer I can send upwards.

Comment: The specs you posted here don't say anything about zero interaction with artists. They have to do *something* to support your workflow. How else are you going to know which one of the 200 old screws the new one represents?

Comment: That's actually a question I asked and I haven't gotten an answer. I don't even know who the artists *are* and the idea is for this project to be utilized by teams of people who aren't even my company at an unknown point in time in the future.

Comment: Oh, that's... difficult. You'll want to come up with a set of instructions that artists will follow. You simply can't support an artist's arbitrary workflow (unless you start coding 3ds max plugins at least).I actually think most 3D packages give new objects unique names. You can simply require them to keep the names constant.